# how to create sorting animation in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, sorting

I am trying to create a sorting visualizer in react js for a project.

As for now, I implemented only bubble sort but I am planning to implement also quick sort, merge sort, and many more

how can I add a nice animation that shows step by step how the sorting algorithms fundamentally work?

Do I need to update the array every time I am making a change or there are other ways to do that?

SortingVisualizer.tsx

```
import "./SortingVisualizer.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import * as sortings from "../sortingAlgorithms";
// Change this value for the number of bars (value) in the array.
const NUMBER_OF_ARRAY_BARS = 50;
// This is the main color of the array bars.
const PRIMARY_COLOR = "turquoise";

function SortingVisualizer() {
  const [array, setArray] = useState<number[]>([]);

  const resetArray = () => {
    const randomNumbers = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ARRAY_BARS; i++) {
      randomNumbers.push(randomIntFromInterval(5, 730));
    }
    setArray(randomNumbers);
  };

  const bubbleSort = () => {
    setArray(sortings.bubbleSort(array.slice()));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    resetArray();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="array-container">
      {array.map((value, idx) => (
        <div
          className="array-bar"
          key={idx}
          style={{
            backgroundColor: PRIMARY_COLOR,
            height: `${value}px`,
          }}
        ></div>
      ))}
      <button onClick={bubbleSort}>Bubble Sort</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SortingVisualizer;

function randomIntFromInterval(min: number, max: number) {
  // min and max included
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

SortingVisualizer.css

```
.array-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    /* top: 100px; */
}

.array-bar {
    width: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 1px;
}
```

sortingAlgorithms.ts

```
export const bubbleSort = (arr: number[]) => {
  const length = arr.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < length - i - 1; j++) {
      if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
        swap(arr, j, j + 1);
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
};

const swap = (arr: number[], i: number, j: number) => {
  const temp = arr[i];
  arr[i] = arr[j];
  arr[j] = temp;
};
```